# Siri implementation in IONIC- Cli 5.4.13 Native

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native, sirishortcuts

When i install Cordova Plugin cli command some exception get  error display in below

Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "glob" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

How to implementation IONIC Native -Siri

Comment: I will used url for implement Siri Shortcuts in Ionic with angular.
https://medium.com/@vik.ceo/using-siri-shortcuts-with-your-ionic-3-app-c3ba2e497715
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/siri-shortcuts/
but I'm struggling in installing plugins(cordova-plugin-siri-shortcuts). 
get same error
Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "glob" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-siri-shortcuts exited with exit code1.

Answer (score 0):

This error sometimes implies that the plugin is not compatible with your project's cordova version. Try downgrading to Cordova 8, I think ionic 5 application comes loaded with Cordova 9. Add cordova dev dependancy as

```
npm install cordova@8.0.0 --save-dev
```